# Software for American basket option pricing using Longstaff-Schwartz/Least Squares Monte Carlo method

Tags: american-options, software, basket

Is there free software (preferably in Python) that computes American basket (high-dimensional!) option prices in the Black Scholes model using the Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm (also known as Least Squares Monte Carlo)?

Optimally, I want to be able to control the number of basis functions, the number of Monte Carlo samples and the number of time steps used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuantLib is what you are looking for. It is free/open source library written in C++, it is available in Python as well (via SWIG): https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml

Examples are shipped with QuantLib and among them some show how to price options.

To get a feel for what it's like, you can check this blog post, explaining how to price an American option on a single asset using a binomial tree in Python:
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/american-option-pricing-quantlib-python.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It works quite nicely, but I have a question on the configuration of the Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm, in case you want to check it out: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39614/quantlib-how-to-change-polynomial-order-in-mcamericanbasketengine