# QuantLib: How to change polynomial order in MCAmericanBasketEngine?

Tags: american-options, quantlib, basket

My goal is to price American basket put options using the Least squares Monte Carlo, or Longstaff-Schwartz algorithm.

I currently have the one-dimensional case working with the Python file below (I am using the SWIG package), but I would like to change the number of basis functions used by the AmericanBasketEngine to make sure the price is accurate. How do I do this?

Looking at the C++ source, I found the `polynomOrder` keyword argument with default value `2` of the class `AmericanBasketPathPricer`. However, I do not know how this class is connected to the `MCAmericanBasketEngine`, which does not have such a keyword argument. (I never programmed in either `C` or `C++`, so I am quite lost in the source.)

Maybe is the polynomial order determined automatically, based on the `requiredTolerance`? That would be ideal, but I couldn't find a description of what the `MCAmericanBasketEngine` does exactly anywhere.

```
from QuantLib import *

d=1 #To be increased...
todaysDate = Date(15,May,1998)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
settlementDate = Date(17,May,1998)
riskFreeRate = FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.05, Actual365Fixed())

payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Put, 100.0)

underlying1 = SimpleQuote(100.0)
volatility1 = BlackConstantVol(todaysDate, TARGET(), 0.30, Actual365Fixed())
dividendYield1 = FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.00, Actual365Fixed())
process1 = BlackScholesMertonProcess(QuoteHandle(underlying1),
                                    YieldTermStructureHandle(dividendYield1),
                                    YieldTermStructureHandle(riskFreeRate),
                                    BlackVolTermStructureHandle(volatility1))
procs = StochasticProcessVector()
procs.push_back(process1)

matrix = Matrix(1,1)
matrix[0][0] = 1.0
process = StochasticProcessArray(procs, matrix)
american_exercise = AmericanExercise(Date(17,May,1998),Date(17,May,1999))
basketoption = BasketOption(AverageBasketPayoff(payoff,d),american_exercise)
basketoption.setPricingEngine(
    MCAmericanBasketEngine(
        process,
        'pseudorandom',
        polynomOrder = 2,#keyword does not exist
        timeStepsPerYear = 100,
        requiredTolerance = 0.01,
        #seed = 42))
    )
)
print(basketoption.NPV())
```

Answer (score 1):

As per QuantLib's lead developer, `polynomOrder` is indeed not currently exposed. There is now a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/469) about this.

Comment: If it's just a matter of exposition in the Python SWIG wrappers, you could add it yourself (locally on your machine or via a pull request) here:  
https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/master/SWIG/basketoptions.i

   
you have an example here (1D options) where the parameter is exposed to Python: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/47dd2bb0ecf97eb1dc7922fb86f1c05e89d2f3f9/SWIG/options.i

Anyway, I think you should move the issue here: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG